# HTTP Header not correct in PHP

Tags: php, http-referer

I have links that add a row to the database and then redirect to another page. In that page I want to show a message of success if it came from the insert page however the `HTTP_REFERER` doesn't acknowledge that page as the referer and instead shows the previous page.

So `page-one.php` contains a hyperlink:

```
http://example.com/add.php?c=359
```

and on add.php

```
header('Location: http://example.com/rows.php');
```

on rows.php I am expecting add.php to be the referer but it isn't instead page-one.php is.

How do I make add.php to be the referer cos that's where it is being redirected from?

Comment: Either put it in the url or save it in a session variable

Comment: @JohnConde just thought of that whilst getting a drink, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way it is with `$_SESSION` variables. Whenever you need to show a message add it:

```
$_SESSION['messages'][] = "your message";
```

Then, when you are on a page (any non-redirected page), show all of them and erase the content with:

```
$_SESSION['messages'] = array();
```